# Cannot connect to Lego Mindstorms Robot Inventor 51515 from within the official Lego app using BlueTooth

Tags: macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, lego-mindstorms

Cannot connect to Mindstorms Robot Inventor 51515 hub from Macbook pro using Bluetooth

I am trying to connect my macbook pro with the 51515 using bluetooth but I get a prompt to enter a passcode - and I dont have one. On the other hand I am able to connect with my ipad/android phone without any passcode. Any ideas whats going on?

About the Macbook pro :

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
- macOs Big Sur v 11.1
- Support BLE

Thanks.

Comment: Your MacBook should be compatible since it uses Bluetooth 4.0. Someone on windows had a similar problem and solved it by removing the 51515 from the Bluetooth options menu in windows. https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15809/robot-inventor-51515-pin-request-when-connecting-via-bluetooth maybe this works for you as well?

Comment: Are you trying to connect via the app or via System Preferences?